# Sitecore Automated Republish

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, sitecore

Is there any way of automating a site publish with a given set of targets in Sitecore through the command line?

I have the PowerShell console installed however how do I know what commands it even supports? Documentation seems sparse.

Comment: Your question is tagged `msbuild`, so when you say you want to publish your site given "a set of targets...through the command line" do you mean you are looking to publish your Sitecore site as part of the build process aka `msbuild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend Sitecore Powershell Console created by Adam Najmanowicz. There is a lot of documentation and sample commands on his blog. You can find a code that will publish pages [here http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2011/11/17/powershell-console-for-sitecore-what-can-it-do-for-me/](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2011/11/17/powershell-console-for-sitecore-what-can-it-do-for-me/).

More information and other commands can be found in other posts on his blog.